# Bad PBR signature in centOS

Tags: linux, centos, dd

Please help,I had 80gb harddisk of CentOS 6 with full important files.Unfortunately it shows bad PBR signature.I want to copy all those files and configuration files to another fresh harddisk of size 80gb and run the programs well.
Please suggest me to take steps ahead.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

install a new OS on the second hard disk and attach the second drive as a secondary drive.  make sure you mount it and then copy the files to the new hard disk.

Comment: Great Thanks for your reply, I had installed OS in secondary harddisk and mounted too.for copying files from secondary to primary hdd shall i use this command dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda conv=noerror,sync.where sdb is secondary hdd installed only OS.and sda is bad pbr signature.if any other codes left then please let me know.